# Why does the datatype remain the same after converting the matrix into a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, types

```
mat
     days  temp   rain    precip humidity
[1,] "Mon" "31.2" "TRUE"  "1.2"  "62.4"  
[2,] "Tue" "27.3" "TRUE"  "7.6"  "96.3"  
[3,] "Wed" "28.7" "TRUE"  "8.3"  "97.6"  
[4,] "Thu" "32.5" "FALSE" "0.8"  "73.2"  
[5,] "Fri" "33.8" "FALSE" "0.2"  "55.3" 

weather.df3 <-as.data.frame(mat)
weather.df3
  days temp  rain precip humidity
1  Mon 31.2  TRUE    1.2     62.4
2  Tue 27.3  TRUE    7.6     96.3
3  Wed 28.7  TRUE    8.3     97.6
4  Thu 32.5 FALSE    0.8     73.2
5  Fri 33.8 FALSE    0.2     55.3

class(weather.df3$humidity)
[1] "character"
class(weather.df3$temp)
[1] "character"
class(weather.df3$rain)
[1] "character"
```

I created a matrix "mat" and converted it into a dataframe "weather.df3".

Why does the data type still remain as "character" even after I have converted the matrix into a dataframe ? I thought by converting into a dataframe using "as.data.frame()", the data types will be reverted to the 'correct' data type ? i.e humidity values will be forced back to 'numeric', likewise for the other columns.

Do I have to manually extract individual column using `$` to convert the columns into the correct data type?

Answer (score 3):

It's difficult to answer *why* questions. There's a case for `as.data.frame` trying to convert to a more appropriate type from a matrix, but also lots of reasons for not doing it (unpredictable behaviour, performance, risk of getting it wrong). Apparently the [R Core Team](https://www.r-project.org/contributors.html) came down on the latter side but I don't know the precise reason(s).

Converting the types is straightforward though. Here's your data frame with all character columns:

```r
dat
#   days temp  rain precip humidity
# 1  Mon 31.2  TRUE    1.2     62.4
# 2  Tue 27.3  TRUE    7.6     96.3
# 3  Wed 28.7  TRUE    8.3     97.6
# 4  Thu 32.5 FALSE    0.8     73.2
# 5  Fri 33.8 FALSE    0.2     55.3
sapply(dat, class)

       days        temp        rain      precip    humidity 
"character" "character" "character" "character" "character"
```

We can use [`type.convert()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/type.convert.html):

```r
dat2  <- type.convert(dat, as.is  = TRUE)
sapply(dat2, class)
#        days        temp        rain      precip    humidity 
# "character"   "numeric"   "logical"   "numeric"   "numeric"
```

Note that `as.is` is basically the negation of `stringsAsFactors`, and you will usually want it to be `TRUE`. From the docs:

> `as.is`: whether to store strings as plain character. When false, convert character vectors to factors.

The `readr` package also has [`type_convert()`](https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/type_convert.html), a similar function with some extra parameters around white space and locale.

##### Data

```r
dat  <- structure(list(days = c("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"), temp = c("31.2", 
"27.3", "28.7", "32.5", "33.8"), rain = c("TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", 
"FALSE", "FALSE"), precip = c("1.2", "7.6", "8.3", "0.8", "0.2"
), humidity = c("62.4", "96.3", "97.6", "73.2", "55.3")), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "data.frame")
```